how to get my datadog agent to record logs from nginx which is monitoring a website?
As above. I work at a bookshop which runs a website. Due to hacking issues, we've started monitoring urls visiting the website.
Someone at the IT company we used has set up nginx and postgresql monitoring which is being fed into datadog. I can see the monitoring with the login information to datadog.
However, I'm trying to set up the datadog agent on my local machine so we can record logs of the visit urls. I've tried following the datadog documentation, but I don't quite understand how I can get the logs nginx is supposedly writing to be sent to my local agent.
I have created an nginx configuration file but not sure which url I'm supposed to use. Should it be a url connected to the datadog website? Or host ip address of our website? Or something else?
Sorry, I know this is probably a really easy problem to solve but I'm quite inexperienced with web monitoring and web development.
logs_enabled = true for datadog.yaml
nginx conf.yaml I've tried as both localhost (even though the website is hosted on AWS) as well as the ip address of the server hosting the website. Both with and without the /nginxstatus/ at the end of the path.

I think the confusion is in the line how I can get the logs nginx is supposedly writing to be sent to my local agent - the Datadog agent collects data and sends it to Datadog, it does not receive data. You probably want to look at exporting logs.
